# Can transactions be managed by container when datasource is defined outside the container?

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, jta

Can I combine datasource, which is defined programmatically in application with container managed transaction?

Context information:
I would like to create datasource in runtime, because username and password for database will be retrieved from another service during startup of my service. As far as I know to achieve that I should create datasource programmatically in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can: for example you can add your datasource to your own transaction manager, for example using [Spring transactions](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364115/defining-a-jta-datasource-outside-of-the-container) for more details, and [here](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-data-jta) for a further example.